# Custom Gradient Boosting Classifier implementation. No training progress

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm trying to implement a `GradientBoostingClassifier`
I took the algorithm from the StatQuest video ([Gradient Boost Part 4 (of 4): Classification Details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StWY5QWMXCw&t=1355s)) and trying to implement it using `numpy` + `sklearn.DecisionTreeRegressor` as a base model.

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

def sigmoid(x):
  if x > 0:   
    z = np.exp(-x)
    return 1/(1+z)
  else:
    z = np.exp(x)
    return z/(1+z)

class GradientBoostingClassifier():
  def __init__(self, n_estimators=20, lr=0.1):
    self.n_estimators = n_estimators
    self.lr = lr
    self.training_history = {
        'log_loss': [], 'roc_auc': [], 'pr_auc': []
    }
    self.base_learners = []

  def fit(self, X, y):
    data = X.copy()
    features = data.columns
    # 1. Initialize model with a constant value:
    p = y.sum() / len(y)
    odds = p / (1-p)
    log_odds = np.log(odds)
    data['cur_log_odds'] = log_odds
    data['prediction'] = data['cur_log_odds'].apply(sigmoid)

    self.training_history['log_loss'].append( log_loss(y, data['prediction']) )
    self.training_history['roc_auc'].append( roc_auc_score(y, data['prediction']) )
    self.training_history['pr_auc'].append( average_precision_score(y, data['prediction']) )

    # 2. For m = 1 to M:
    for _ in tqdm(range(self.n_estimators)):
      # 2.1 Compute so-called pseudo-residuals:
      data['residuals'] = (data['prediction'] - y)

      # 2.2 Fit a base learner regressor to predict pseudo-residuals:
      base_learner = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=3,  min_samples_split=2, random_state=42)
      base_learner.fit(data[features], data['residuals'])
      self.base_learners.append(base_learner)

      # 2.3 For each leaf calculate its output log-odds
      # get leaf number from Regression tree
      data['leaf'] = base_learner.apply(data[features])

      # compute output log-odd as sum(residuals) / sum(old_prediction * (1 - old_prediction))
      leafs_output = data.groupby('leaf', as_index=False).apply(
          lambda d: d['residuals'].sum() / (0.00001+(d['prediction'] * (1-d['prediction']) ).sum())
      ).rename(columns={None: 'lambda_odds'})

      data = data.merge(leafs_output, on='leaf')
      # 2.4 Update current_log_odds =  current_log_odds + lr*predicted_log_odds
      data['cur_log_odds'] += self.lr*data['lambda_odds']
      data = data.drop('lambda_odds', axis=1)

      data['prediction'] = data['cur_log_odds'].apply(sigmoid)

      self.training_history['log_loss'].append( log_loss(y, data['prediction']) )
      self.training_history['roc_auc'].append( roc_auc_score(y, data['prediction']) )
      self.training_history['pr_auc'].append( average_precision_score(y, data['prediction']) )

    return data

  def predict_proba(self, X):
    pass
```

The problem is that even after 1000 iterations (`n_estimators = 1000`) my `roc_auc` and `pr_auc` scores are close to what the random model gives (`roc_auc=0.5`, `pr_auc=0.29` which is a proportion of the positive class).

What am I doing wrong?

An sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier implementation gives much higher scores on the same dataset even with `n_estimators = 10`

Comment: Hi I guess that means, that your model just predicts one case. It could be, that your model can't use the attributes because either they contain no usable information to clasify better than a constant classifier, or because the attributes are in the wrong format.

Comment: As I mentioned, an sklearn implementation gets good accuracy on the same data, so the problem is not in data, but in my implementation

Comment: Oh I see. Then I guess you have to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of debugging I figured out that

```py
data.merge(leafs_output, on='leaf')
```

function merge reorders the rows of the left dataframe, so that my `data` dataframe gets reordered on the every interation

```py
data.merge(leafs_output, on='leaf', how='left')
```

solves the issue